# Instalação Phalcon PHP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Olá,

Estou tentando instalar o Framework Phalcon PHP no XAMPP em Windows conforme o tutorial desse link: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html#id2, porém seguindo os passos do tutorial, depois que eu coloco a dll do Phalcon na pasta de extensões do PHP, ao reiniciar o Apache, ele acusa o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro Apache]

Alguém saberia me ajudar.. ? Agradeço a atenção, qualquer ajuda é muito bem vinda.

Comment: Parece-me que não fizeste o download da versão correcta do Phalcon para utilizar com o teu setup e versão de PHP.

Comment: Opa, obrigado. Sim, pois é, eu estava tentando instalar com a dll non thread safe, agora baixei a correta, porém está acusando outro erro agora, no momento de iniciar o apache: "Não foi possível localizar o ponto de entrada do procedimento zval_property_ctor na biblioteca de vínculo dinâmico php5ts.dll", estou pesquisando, mas até o momento não achei a solução. Se puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Pessoal, resolvido, obrigado pela atenção. vlw :)

Comment: Use versão 32Bits do phalcon VC11.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo erro que estás a obter, parece que não estás a fazer o [download da versão correcta do Phalcon](http://phalconphp.com/en/download/windows) a ser utilizado com o teu *setup* e versão do PHP.

*Assumindo PHP 5.5.0*

### PHP *Non-Thread-Safe* (nts)

Se tiveres a versão de PHP *Non-Thread-Safe* (nts), precisas de fazer o download:

- Windows 32bits - [Phalcon 1.3.2 - Windows x86 for PHP 5.5.0 NTS (VC11)](http://static.phalconphp.com/files/phalcon_x86_VC11_php5.5.0_1.3.2_nts.zip)
- Windows 64bits - [Phalcon 1.3.2 - Windows x64 for PHP 5.5.0 NTS (VC11)](http://static.phalconphp.com/files/phalcon_x64_VC11_php5.5.0_1.3.2_nts.zip)

### PHP *Thread-Safe* (ts)

Se tiveres a versão de PHP *Thread-Safe* (ts), precisas de fazer o download:

- Windows 32Bits - [Phalcon 1.3.2 - Windows x86 for PHP 5.5.0 (VC11)](http://static.phalconphp.com/files/phalcon_x86_VC11_php5.5.0_1.3.2.zip)
- Windows 64Bits - [Phalcon 1.3.2 - Windows x64 for PHP 5.5.0 (VC11)](http://static.phalconphp.com/files/phalcon_x64_VC11_php5.5.0_1.3.2.zip)